# using eval() on json data

Tags: ajax, django, json, eval

I'm trying to use eval on a json formatted dataset to retrieve the value of an attribute i.e.,

```
[{"item_one":1, "item_two": 2, "item_three": 3}]
```

I'm using dajax for the ajax call within django like this:

```
@dajaxice_register
def get_current_id(request):
    home_timeline = oauth_req(
    'http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/home_timeline.json?count=1',
    settings.TWITTER_TOKEN_KEY,
    settings.TWITTER_TOKEN_SECRET
    )
    return simplejson.dumps({'home_timeline': home_timeline })
```

which gets this as it's callback:

```
function get_current_id_callback(data){
      if(data==Dajaxice.EXCEPTION){
        alert('Error! Something happens!');
      }
      else{
        console.log(data.home_timeline);
      }
    }
```

I don't understand why this gives me undefined:

```
console.log(eval(data.home_timeline.item_one))
```

what's the correct way to retrieve the value of item_one?

Thanks.

Comment: Quit that.  Every language in common use today has a JSON parser either built in or readily available.  Especially Javascript.  Check out `JSON.parse`.  It's way safer and usually more efficient than `eval`.  Your framework may even be doing it for you already.

Comment: @cHao, using JSON.parse still doesn't parse `data.home_timeline.item_one` correctly, gives: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
get_current_id_callback:8000/:64` which is: `console.log(JSON.parse(data.home_timeline.id_str));` Thanks.

Comment: And when you say `console.log(data)` (or possibly `console.log(data.home_timeline)`), what does that give you?

Comment: That gives me the json output.

Comment: Then `JSON.parse` will give you the object the JSON represents, if it's valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If `data` is still a string, then you need to `eval(data)` (or as @cHao suggests, parse it) to yield a javascript object capable of being dereferenced.

If it's not just a string, it should not be eval'd first.

Comment: eval and JSON.parse both work when iterating over the object, which contains one index - shouldn't be necessary to have to iterate over one index. This works: `$.each(eval(data.home_timeline), function(i, item){
                  console.log(item.id_str);
              });` and this also works:   `$.each(JSON.parse(data.home_timeline), function(i, item){
                  console.log(item.id_str);
              });`. So, why doesn't it work without `$each()`?

Comment: Thanks, figured it out: `parsed = JSON.parse(data.home_timeline);
              console.log(parsed[0].id_str);`